# Unable to get value for uuid in node

Tags: node.js

This is very simple but I'm not be able to find out why the code below is not pulling the value of roomId. hence can you check and help?

```
const { v4: uuidV4 }= require('uuid')
app.get('/:room',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('room',{roomId: req.params.room })
})

console.log(roomId);
```

Here's the error from nodemon below:

```
console.log(roomId);
            ^
ReferenceError: roomId is not defined
```

can you please help?

Comment: Hi, `roomId` as a variable is definitely not defined anywhere within your code. Because of scoping, you cannot read `roomId` on that line. 

Instead, try this 
`const { v4: uuidV4 }= require('uuid')
app.get('/:room',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.params.room);
    res.render('room',{roomId: req.params.room })
})`

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable declared as `roomId`.

```js
const { v4: uuidV4 }= require('uuid') // this line is not even used 
app.get('/:room',(req,res)=> {
    const roomId = req.params.room;
    console.log(roomId)
    res.render('room', {roomId})
})
```

You have to do like this if you want to log.